# Error on SQL Connection String in Powershell

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to run a sql query from powershell as a scheduled job in SQL server (it's then getting emailed out by the same powershell script) and getting an error I can't sort out.

```
###

$SqlServer = “localhost”
$SqlCatalog = “myDatabase”
$SqlQuery = “select * from MY_VIEW″
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = “server=$SqlServer;Database=$SqlCatalog; user id = myUserid; password=myPassword”
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
```

This is the error I receive:

A job step received an error at line 7 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is '$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "server=$SqlServer;Database=$SqlCatalog; user id = myUserid; password=myPassword"'. Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'Unexpected token 'server=$SqlServer' in expression or statement.  '.

What's wrong with my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code sample contains "smart" quotes. That is, instead of ordinary double quote `"` (0x22), you have `“` (0x201c) and `”` (0x201d) (look carefully to see that double quote is stright up and smart ones curve).

This shouldn't be a problem, though "smart" quotes are **really** stupid an idea, especially when they are automagically used to format, say, blog posts containing code samples.

When copy-pasted to an editor or directly into Powershell, the statement

```
$SqlQuery = “select * from MY_VIEW″
```

won't have a closing quote but an question mark like so,

```
$SqlQuery = “select * from MY_VIEW?
```

This creates an unbalanced string quotation, so the script breaks. The weird quote char is likely to be double prime quote `″` (0x301c).

For a solution, purge the "smart" quotes very carefully and use the ordinary `"` double quote. Make sure you use decent an editor like Notepad++ and not a word processor like Wordpad or Word.

Comment: That was it! Thanks. I actually did copy the code (stolen shamelessly from another site) to notepad++, but apparently that doesn't catch those.